# Не хочет срабатывать ID со слешем

Tags: javascript

```
 $('#/catalog/avtosvet/').css("display","none");
```

Не срабатывает, а если слеши убрать, то работает, что же делать? Их как то экранировать нужно?

> убрать слеши не вариант, это в битриксе smart фильтр так работает, там в id прописан путь

Comment: убрать слеши не вариант, это в битриксе smart фильтр так работает, там в id прописан путь

Comment: добавь пример, как это в разметке выглядит

Comment: Из необходимости сохранить слезши попробуйте такие варианты:

1. `$(document.getElementById("/catalog/avtosvet/")).css("display","none");`

2. Попробуйте вообще сделать `console.log(document.getElementById("/catalog/avtosvet/"));` помсотрите, найдет ли что. 
3. Если это `div` элемент, воспользуйтесь циклом по всем div элементам и проверьте атрибут id. Например:

    $("div").each(function(index, element){
         if($(element).attr("id") == "/catalog/avtosvet/"){ 
             console.log(element);
         }
    
    });


Третий вариант не подведет (ну это было бы странно)).

Answer (score 2):

Вы используете селектор jQuery через идентификатор.

Идентификатор не должен начинаться со слэша и содержать слэши, так как этот символ является недопустимым, должен начинаться с символа, в качестве разделителя удобно использовать знак тире.

> Идентификатор должен обязательно начинаться с латинского символа и
>   может содержать в себе латинские буквы `A–Z`, `a–z`, цифры `0–9`, символ
>   дефиса `-` и подчеркивания `_`. Использование русских букв в именах
>   идентификатора недопустимо. Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.

- [ID Selector (“#id”)](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)
- [HTML id Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp)
- [Атрибут id](http://htmlbook.ru/html/attr/id)

Рабочий пример с корректным значением идентификатора (подсветим фон кнопки красным цветом):

```js
$('#catalog-avtosvet').css("background","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="catalog-avtosvet">Red button</button>
```